# Create a Pandas DataFrame from deeply nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to create a single Pandas DataFrame object from a deeply nested JSON string.

The JSON schema is:

```
{"intervals": [
{
pivots: "Jane Smith",
"series": [
    {
        "interval_id": 0,
        "p_value": 1
       },
     {
         "interval_id": 1,
         "p_value": 1.1162791357932633e-8
     },
   {
        "interval_id": 2,
        "p_value": 0.0000028675012051504467
     }
    ],
   },
  {

"pivots": "Bob Smith",
  "series": [
       {
            "interval_id": 0,
            "p_value": 1
           },
         {
             "interval_id": 1,
            "p_value": 1.1162791357932633e-8
         },
       {
            "interval_id": 2,
            "p_value": 0.0000028675012051504467
         }
       ]
     }
    ]
 }
```

**Desired Outcome** I need to flatten this to produce a table:

```
Actor Interval_id Interval_id Interval_id ... 
Jane Smith      1         1.1162        0.00000 ... 
Bob Smith       1         1.1162        0.00000 ...
```

The first column is the `Pivots` values, and the remaining columns are the values of the keys `interval_id` and `p_value` stored in the list `series`.

So far i've got

```
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
actor_data = r.get("url/to/data").json['data']['intervals']
df = pd.DataFrame(actor_data)
```

`actor_data` is a list where the length is equal to the number of individuals ie `pivots.values()`. The df object simply returns

```
<bound method DataFrame.describe of  pivots             Series
0           Jane Smith  [{u'p_value': 1.0, u'interval_id': 0}, {u'p_va...
1           Bob Smith  [{u'p_value': 1.0, u'interval_id': 0}, {u'p_va...
.
.
.
```

How can I iterate through that `series` list to get to the dict values and create N distinct columns? Should I try to create a DataFrame for the `series` list, reshape it,and then do a column bind with the actor names?

UPDATE:

```
pvalue_list = [i['p_value'] for i in json_data['series']]
```

this gives me a list of lists. Now I need to figure out how to add each list as a row in a DataFrame.

```
value_list = []
for i in pvalue_list:
    pvs = [j['p_value'] for j in i]
    value_list = value_list.append(pvs)
return value_list
```

This returns a NoneType

**Solution**

```
def get_hypthesis_data():
    raw_data = r.get("/url/to/data").json()['data']
    actor_dict = {}
    for actor_series in raw_data['intervals']:
        actor = actor_series['pivots']
        p_values = []
        for interval in actor_series['series']:
            p_values.append(interval['p_value'])
        actor_dict[actor] = p_values
    return pd.DataFrame(actor_dict).T
```

This returns the correct DataFrame. I transposed it so the individuals were rows and not columns.

Comment: The `list.append` method doesn't return anything (well, it returns `None` because all Python functions return something) because it updates the list inplace. Just remove `value_list = ` and your list will be properly updated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think organizing your data in way that yields repeating column names is only going to create headaches for you later on down the road. A better approach IMHO is to create a column for each of `pivots`, `interval_id`, and `p_value`. This will make extremely easy to query your data after loading it into pandas.

Also, your JSON has some errors in it. I ran it through [this](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to find the errors.

[`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) helps here

```
import sh
jq = sh.jq.bake('-M')  # disable colorizing
json_data = "from above"
rule = """[{pivots: .intervals[].pivots, 
            interval_id: .intervals[].series[].interval_id,
            p_value: .intervals[].series[].p_value}]"""
out = jq(rule, _in=json_data).stdout
res = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(out))
```

This will yield output similar to

```
    interval_id       p_value      pivots
32            2  2.867501e-06  Jane Smith
33            2  1.000000e+00  Jane Smith
34            2  1.116279e-08  Jane Smith
35            2  2.867501e-06  Jane Smith
36            0  1.000000e+00   Bob Smith
37            0  1.116279e-08   Bob Smith
38            0  2.867501e-06   Bob Smith
39            0  1.000000e+00   Bob Smith
40            0  1.116279e-08   Bob Smith
41            0  2.867501e-06   Bob Smith
42            1  1.000000e+00   Bob Smith
43            1  1.116279e-08   Bob Smith
```

Adapted from [this comment](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4007#issuecomment-21375565)

Of course, you can always call `res.drop_duplicates()` to remove the duplicate rows. This gives

```
In [175]: res.drop_duplicates()
Out[175]:
    interval_id       p_value      pivots
0             0  1.000000e+00  Jane Smith
1             0  1.116279e-08  Jane Smith
2             0  2.867501e-06  Jane Smith
6             1  1.000000e+00  Jane Smith
7             1  1.116279e-08  Jane Smith
8             1  2.867501e-06  Jane Smith
12            2  1.000000e+00  Jane Smith
13            2  1.116279e-08  Jane Smith
14            2  2.867501e-06  Jane Smith
36            0  1.000000e+00   Bob Smith
37            0  1.116279e-08   Bob Smith
38            0  2.867501e-06   Bob Smith
42            1  1.000000e+00   Bob Smith
43            1  1.116279e-08   Bob Smith
44            1  2.867501e-06   Bob Smith
48            2  1.000000e+00   Bob Smith
49            2  1.116279e-08   Bob Smith
50            2  2.867501e-06   Bob Smith

[18 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: wow good call on using `jq`! I feel like i'm getting closer. If I change the `jq` rule to `rule = """[.intervals[].series]"""` that will allow me to build a DataFrame with the correct N x K dimensions. The problem is that each cell is a dict eg `{u'p_value': 1, u'interval_id': 0}` instead of just the value of `p_value`.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem for `DataFrame`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the values of the cells so that they contain only the value of `p_value` and not the entire dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give me an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: sure. I'm trying to build a DataFrame where the columns are time intervals and the rows are individuals. within each cell should be a single number (p_value) eg 0.5.

Currently I have the correct dimensions; 22 rows (1 for each person) and 27 columns (1 for each time-period + 1 for person's name). The problem: 

for row `Jane Smith` at `time_period 1` the value of the cell is `{u'p_value: 0.034, u'interval_id: 1}`. I'm trying to get the value of the cell to be `0.034` instead of the entire dict, for all time periods and individuals. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I'm trying to repeat this for a `json` file but can't properly set `_in` parameter for `jq()`. Is it possible to feed in a `json` file to `sh`?

Comment: @Anton: Not sure what has changed since early 2014, but as far as I can tell `jq` does not accept a string as a command line argument. Instead, you can create a `cat = sh.cat`, and then pipe it into `jq`: `jq(cat(_in=json_data), rule).stdout`. See http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#piping

Comment: The resulting `stdout` from `jq` has lots of `\n` in there and is actually a bytestring, but calling `.decode('utf8')` on it yields a `str`, which can then be easily passed to `json.loads()`, which in turn happily gives you a new `dict`.