# Search element in Series with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a following JSON file (see link below) that I read from the web. I would like to search for a specific string and return the index of it.

Also, if there is a better way to read and manipulate JSON data other than how I use it here, I would like to know. Thanks!

[JSON FILE](https://db.tt/PHS9Lz2Q)

Here's how I read the file:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
#-------------------------------------------------
# READING IN THE JSON FILE 
#-------------------------------------------------
path = 'ads_nasa.txt'
records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
frame = DataFrame(records)
```

I tried to use the following but it does not work:

```
frame.author[0].find('Deshpande, R.')
```

How do I search for a string and find its index in a Pandas Core Series?

Comment: Also, when I use pd.read_json(path) I get an error, "arrays must all be same length". So, I resorted to use the above method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case use the `index` method of `list` objects:

```
frame.author[0].index('Deshpande, R.')
```

I would recommend looking into filtering your JSON prior to putting it into a `DataFrame` so that you can take advantage of all the indexing operations that are available in pandas. Check out this question and answer for an example: [Create a Pandas DataFrame from deeply nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21494030/564538).