# flatten a deep json structure with jq for pandas

Tags: jquery, python, json, pandas

I am trying to flatten a JSON file to a pandas dataframe and found a solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494030/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-deeply-nested-json). In my case the JSON has so many different attributes that it seems so tedious to spell out the rule for every field manually. Isn't it possible flatten every attribute in the JSON file automatically?

Comment: may help to give a toy example

Answer (score 3):

I just made something to solve a similar problem. This might not work in your case, but maybe you could take similar approach.

```
def nested_dataframe(d):
    assert type(d) is dict  # may be a nested dict
    types = map(type, d.values())
    if dict not in types:
        # This is one un-nested dict. Make it a DataFrame.
        return DataFrame.from_dict({k: list([v]) for k, v in d.items()}, orient='index')
    if all([t is dict for t in types]):
        # This is a dict of dicts.
        # Call nested_dataframe on each item, and concatenate the results.
        return pd.concat([nested_dataframe(a) for a in d.values()], keys=d.keys())
    else:
        raise ValueError("This doesn't work on dicts with unequal depths.")
```

Comment: it did't work for me but this may be a good answer for others here. (in my case the dicts can have different depths). I finally made a lot of work of indices by hand, but now I have a working copy that looks somehow similar to yours.