# Accessing nested JSON data as dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following data

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "company": "XYZ",
        "createdAt": "2014-03-27T23:21:48.758Z",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "abc",
        "lastName": "xyz",
        "linkedinAccount": "",
        "location": "",
        "profilePicture": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "ab0e-profilePicture",
            "url": "url.url.com"
        },
        "registrationGate": "normal",
        "telephone": "",
        "title": "AA",
        "updatedAt": "2014-03-27T23:24:20.220Z",
        "username": "abc@gmail.com",
        "zipcode": "00000"
    } 
    ] 
    }
```

I import the json data using the following code

```
import json
import pandas as pd

from pandas import DataFrame
json_data = pd.read_json('data.json')

print json_data[:2]
```

This prints

```
results
0  {u'linkedinAccount': u'', u'username': u'abc...
1  {u'linkedinAccount': u'zxcflcnv', u'username...

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

when I try to print a column using

```
print df['linkedinAccount']
```

I get the following error

```
KeyError: u'no item named linkedinAccount'
```

How do I access data in the dataframes based on column names?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494030/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-deeply-nested-json

Comment: @U2EF1, it is similar but I think that solution would be less ideal for this situation if you might agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your multiple observations are organized in `json`. But it is clear that what is causing problem is you are having a nested structure for the `"profilePicture"` field. Therefore each observation is expressed as a nested dictionary. You need to convert each observation to a `dataframe` and `concat` them into the final `dataframe` as in this solution.

```
In [3]:
print df
                                             results
0  {u'linkedinAccount': u'', u'username': u'abc@g...
1  {u'linkedinAccount': u'', u'username': u'abc@g...

[2 rows x 1 columns]
In [4]: 
print pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index').T for item in df.results])


  linkedinAccount       username registrationGate firstName title lastName  \
0                  abc@gmail.com           normal       abc    AA      xyz   
0                  abc@gmail.com           normal       abc    AA      xyz   

  company telephone                                     profilePicture  \
0     XYZ            {u'url': u'url.url.com', u'__type': u'File', u...   
0     ABC            {u'url': u'url.url.com', u'__type': u'File', u...   

  location                 updatedAt          email                 createdAt  \
0           2014-03-27T23:24:20.220Z  abc@gmail.com  2014-03-27T23:21:48.758Z   
0           2014-03-27T23:24:20.220Z  abc@gmail.com  2014-03-27T23:21:48.758Z   

  zipcode  
0   00000  
0   00000  

[2 rows x 14 columns]
```

Then you may want to think about how to deal the the `profilePicture` column. You can do what @U2EF1 suggested in the link. But I would probably just break that column into three columns `pfPIC_url`, `pfPIC_type`, `pfPIC_name`