# Creating complex nested dictionaries from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, nested

I'm trying to find a generic way of creating (possibly deeply) nested dictionaries from a flat Pandas DataFrame instance.

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Henry', 'Henry'],
                    'age' : [24, 24, 24, 24, 31, 31],
                    'gender' : ['Male','Male','Male','Male','Male','Male'],
                    'study' : ['Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Philosophy', 'Physics', 'Physics'],
                    'course' : ['Calculus 101', 'Calculus 101', 'Calculus 102', 'Aristotelean Ethics', 'Quantum mechanics', 'Quantum mechanics'],
                    'test' : ['Exam', 'Essay','Exam','Essay', 'Exam1','Exam2'],
                    'pass' : [True, True, True, True, True, True],
                    'grade' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']})
dat = dat[['name', 'age', 'gender', 'study', 'course', 'test', 'grade', 'pass']] #re-order columns to better reflect data structure
```

I want to create a deeply nested dictionary (or list of nested dictionaries), that 'respects' the underlying structure of this data. That is, a grade is information about a test, which is part of a course, which is part of a study, that a person does. Also, age and gender are information about that same person.

An example desired output is this:

```
[{'John': {'age': 24,
           'gender': 'Male',
           'study': {'Mathematics': {'Calculus 101': {'Exam': {'grade': 'B',
                                                               'pass': True}}},
                     'Philosophy': {'Aristotelean Ethics': {'Essay': {'grade': 'A',
                                                                      'pass': True}}}}}},
 {'Henry': {'age': 31,
            'gender': 'Male',
            'study': {'Physics': {'Quantum mechanics': {'Exam1': {'Grade': 'C',
                                                                  'Pass': True},
                                                        'Exam2': {'Grade': 'C',
                                                                  'Pass': True}}}}}}]
```

(although there may be other, similar ways to structure such data).

I tried using groupby, which makes it easy, for example, to nest 'grade' and 'pass' under 'test', nest 'test' under 'course', nest 'course' under 'study', and 'study' under 'name'. But, then I don't see how to add 'gender' and 'age' under 'name' as well? Something like this is the best I came up with:

```
dic = {}
for ind, row in dat.groupby(['name', 'study', 'course', 'test'])['grade', 'pass']:

    #this is ugly and not very generic, but just as an example
    if not ind[0] in dic:
        dic[ind[0]] = {}
    if not ind[1] in dic[ind[0]]:
        dic[ind[0]][ind[1]] = {}
    if not ind[2] in dic[ind[0]][ind[1]]:
        dic[ind[0]][ind[1]][ind[2]] = {}
    if not ind[3] in dic[ind[0]][ind[1]][ind[2]]:
        dic[ind[0]][ind[1]][ind[2]][ind[3]] = {}

    dic[ind[0]][ind[1]][ind[2]][ind[3]]['grade'] = row['grade'].values[0]
    dic[ind[0]][ind[1]][ind[2]][ind[3]]['pass'] = row['pass'].values[0]
```

But in this case, 'age' and 'gender' are not nested under 'name'. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this...

Another option is to set a MultiIndex and make a .to_dict('index') call. But then again, I don't see how I can nest both dicts and non-dicts under a single key...

My question is similar to this one:
[Convert pandas DataFrame to a nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798112/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dict), but I'm looking for a more complex nesting (e.g., not just one last column which should be nested under all other columns).
Most other questions on Stackoverflow ask for the reverse: creating a (possibly MultiIndex) DataFrame from a deeply nested dictionary.

Edit: The question is also similar to this q: [Pandas convert Dataframe to Nested Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576869/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-nested-json), but in that question, only the *last* column (e.g., column *n*) should be nested under all other columns (*n-1*, *n-2* etc; fully recursive nesting).
In my question, column *n* and *n-1* should be nested under *n-2*, but column *n-2* and *n-3* should be nested under *n-4* (thus, importantly, *n-2* is *not* nested under *n-3* but under *n-4*). The MultiIndex partial solution offered by Mohammad Yusuf Ghazi depicts the structure nicely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas convert Dataframe to Nested Json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576869/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-nested-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really concise, but it's the best I can get now:

```
>>> def rollup1(x):
...     return x.set_index('test')[['grade', 'pass']].to_dict(orient='index')
>>> def rollup2(x):
...     return x.groupby('course').apply(rollup1).to_dict()
>>> def rollup3(x):
...     return x.groupby('study').apply(rollup2).to_dict()

>>> df = dat.groupby(['name','age','gender']).apply(rollup3)
>>> df.name = 'study'
>>> res = df.reset_index(level=[1,2]).to_dict(orient='index')
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
{'Henry': {'age': 31L,
           'gender': 'Male',
           'study': {'Physics': {'Quantum mechanics': {'Exam1': {'grade': 'C',
                                                                 'pass': True},
                                                       'Exam2': {'grade': 'C',
                                                                 'pass': True}}}}},
 'John': {'age': 24L,
          'gender': 'Male',
          'study': {'Mathematics': {'Calculus 101': {'Essay': {'grade': 'A',
                                                               'pass': True},
                                                     'Exam': {'grade': 'A',
                                                              'pass': True}},
                                    'Calculus 102': {'Exam': {'grade': 'B',
                                                              'pass': True}}},
                    'Philosophy': {'Aristotelean Ethics': {'Essay': {'grade': 'A',
                                                                     'pass': True}}}}}}
```

The idea is to roll up data to dictionaries while grouping data to get 'study' column

**update** 
I've tried to create more generic solution, so it'd work for question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576869/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-nested-json) as well:

```
def rollup_to_dict_core(x, values, columns, d_columns=None):
    if d_columns is None:
        d_columns = []

    if len(columns) == 1:
        if len(values) == 1:
            return x.set_index(columns)[values[0]].to_dict()
        else:
            return x.set_index(columns)[values].to_dict(orient='index')
    else:
        res = x.groupby([columns[0]] + d_columns).apply(lambda y: rollup_to_dict_core(y, values, columns[1:]))
        if len(d_columns) == 0:
            return res.to_dict()
        else:
            res.name = columns[1]
            res = res.reset_index(level=range(1, len(d_columns) + 1))
            return res.to_dict(orient='index')

def rollup_to_dict(x, values, d_columns=None):
    if d_columns is None:
        d_columns = []

    columns = [c for c in x.columns if c not in values and c not in d_columns]
    return rollup_to_dict_core(x, values, columns, d_columns)

>>> pprint(rollup_to_dict(dat, ['pass', 'grade'], ['age','gender']))
{'Henry': {'age': 31L,
           'gender': 'Male',
           'study': {'Physics': {'Quantum mechanics': {'Exam1': {'grade': 'C',
                                                                 'pass': True},
                                                       'Exam2': {'grade': 'C',
                                                                 'pass': True}}}}},
 'John': {'age': 24L,
          'gender': 'Male',
          'study': {'Mathematics': {'Calculus 101': {'Essay': {'grade': 'A',
                                                               'pass': True},
                                                     'Exam': {'grade': 'A',
                                                              'pass': True}},
                                    'Calculus 102': {'Exam': {'grade': 'B',
                                                              'pass': True}}},
                    'Philosophy': {'Aristotelean Ethics': {'Essay': {'grade': 'A',
                                                                     'pass': True}}}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It's not as "pretty" I was hoping for but is very helpful in wrapping my mind around the problem.

Comment: @SMOP wait for it, I'll post generic version soon

Comment: @RomanPekar `{24: {'Male': {'grade': 'A', 'pass': True}},
 31: {'Male': {'grade': 'C', 'pass': True}}}` Prints this on Jupyter notebook (IPython4) python2.7. What's wrong?

Comment: Not sure, probably order of columns of the dataframe. Give me you dataframe and i'll check

Comment: Or have forgot to pass dependent columns?

Comment: This seems to work:
`pprint(rollup_to_dict(dat, ['pass', 'grade'], ['name', 'study', 'course'], ['age', 'gender']))`
Thanks!

Comment: Ah i see the issue, i'll fix it in 30 minutes

Comment: This works: `pprint(rollup_to_dict(df, ['pass', 'grade'], ['name', 'study', 'course','test'], ['age', 'gender']))` Awesome.

Comment: Yes, i think it's better to rewrite it so it will not require columns as a parameters, will do this soon

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi can you check again?

Comment: @RomanPekar name has creeped in and course has creeped out. LOL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131337/discussion-between-roman-pekar-and-mohammad-yusuf-ghazi).

Answer (score 0):

This is partial answer. I don't know how to convert the index to json.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Henry', 'Henry'],
                    'age' : [24, 24, 24, 24, 31, 31],
                    'gender' : ['Male','Male','Male','Male','Male','Male'],
                    'study' : ['Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Mathematics', 'Philosophy', 'Physics', 'Physics'],
                    'course' : ['Calculus 101', 'Calculus 101', 'Calculus 102', 'Aristotelean Ethics', 'Quantum mechanics', 'Quantum mechanics'],
                    'test' : ['Exam', 'Essay','Exam','Essay', 'Exam1','Exam2'],
                    'pass' : [True, True, True, True, True, True],
                    'grade' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']})
df.set_index(keys=['name','age','gender', 'study','course','test','grade','pass'], inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: then use `json.dumps(df.index) ` (don't forget to `import simplejson as json`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also found this partial solution, which very nicely shows the structure of the data that I would like to see in a dict. However, when using json.dumps(df.index) I get a serialization error? (with simplejson):
TypeError: MultiIndex(...) is not JSON serializable