# all rows in df1 that are NOT in df2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df (df1) that looks like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
        ['YYZ', 'SFO', 1],
        ['YYZ', 'YYD', 1],
        ['YYZ', 'EWR', 1],
        ['YYZ', 'DFW', 1],
        ['YYZ', 'LAX', 1],
        ['YYZ', 'YYC', 1]
    ], columns=['city1', 'city2', 'val'])
```

I have another df (df2) that is a subset of df1:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
        ['YYZ', 'SFO', 1],
        ['YYZ', 'YYD', 1]
    ], columns=['city1', 'city2', 'val'])
```

I want all rows in df1 that are NOT in df2.

I've tried various options described in this post [conditional slicing based on values of 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304281/conditional-slicing-based-on-values-of-2-columns), however I haven't been able to get it to work.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe)

Answer (score 6):

- Use `merge` with `indicator=True`
- Then use `query` to strip out only those with `'left_only'`

---

```
df1.merge(
    df2, how='outer', indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)

  city1 city2  val
2   YYZ   EWR    1
3   YYZ   DFW    1
4   YYZ   LAX    1
5   YYZ   YYC    1
```

Comment: This solution produced the correct result. The df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)] solution seemed more intuitive but did not generate the correct results for some reason. I will investigate why and post updates

Answer (score 5):

Just ask the question straight in plain English, hmm I mean in plain pandas. "Select all rows in df1 that are not in df2" translates to:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)]
Out[127]: 
  city1 city2  val
2   YYZ   EWR    1
3   YYZ   DFW    1
4   YYZ   LAX    1
5   YYZ   YYC    1
```

Comment: This solution seemed the most obvious but the results were something I did not expect (not the correct result). I will look further into why and will post some updates.

Comment: Would you care to explain what ~ does in your code df1[~df1.isin(df2)] please? Can't google anything out of it since it's just a symbol. Thanks.

Comment: ~ in this case is a negator. It means NOT whatever comes next. So every True becomes False and vice versa.

Comment: I updated this from `df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)]` to `df1[~df1.isin(df2).any(axis=1)]` and it works much more the way I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

the ~ symbol reverses the isin and makes it effectively a isnotin

Comment: Can you please elaborate? This answer is a bit short and it's not clear where that symbol should go.