# Pandas Dataframe subtraction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

Given two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, each with a unique ID, `ID`, how do I get the elements in `df2` *not* in `df1`?

Right now, my solutions are:

1. df2 - df1 = `pd.concat([df2, df1, df1]).drop_duplicates(subset = 'ID', keep=False)`
2. df1 - df2 = `pd.concat([df2, df2, df1]).drop_duplicates(subset = 'ID', keep=False)`

However, my results are the opposite of what's expected, i.e., RHS(1.) = LHS(2.) and vice versa.

Referring to 1., my logic is that the records in `df1` are removed as `df1` is included twice. Records in `df2` with matching `ID`s to those in `df1` are *also* knocked out. Therefore, the records left are the records in `df2` that *don't* share `ID`s with those in `df1`; said differently, the only records that remain are those found **exclusively in** `df2`.

Pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901322/all-rows-in-df1-that-are-not-in-df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your purpose

```
result= df2[~df2.id.isin(df1.id)]
```